# After NavigationBar Hide on Swipe, Cells appear between HeaderCell & Status Bar for a second

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

**Edit:** I tried adding in AppDelegate `DidFinishLaunch..`

```
let view: UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 25))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
view.alpha = 1
self.window!.rootViewController!.view.addSubview(view)
```

After I changed the Status Bar to red, I prevented it going under status bar, but I realised that it wasn't just the Status Bar and there was something going on with the Navigation Bar while it gets swiped away. The content cells get shown until 1 seconds after NavBar gets swiped away. After 1 seconds, everything seem nice and no content cell gets over the header cell or status bar.

**To clear up the problem, at the time Navigation Bar swipes away, there is a gap forms between Header Cell and status bar, so content cells appear for 1 seconds.**

But how can I prevent this 1-2 second bug? It's the header cell that gives a gap for 1-2 seconds. It mostly occur if I swipe/roll the table view down fast.

I am leaving the original question below for the future readers.

---

**Original Question:**

I have a TableViewController that has Header & Content cells. I am hiding Navigation Controller on Swipe. However, after hiding Nav Bar, Content cells' content goes under the status bar at the top. Everything else is fine.

[image]

Header Cells seem fine, as they stop right below Status Bar.

- `Extend Edges - Top Bars should be checked for the header cell to stop going under status bar but unfortunately doesn't stop content cell.`

---

I tried:

- `self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0)`.
  However, this gives a space between Header Cell & Status Bar (even before the Navigation Bar gets hidden). I want to achieve after hiding the Nav Bar.
- `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false` does nothing.
- `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` Using this anchors the HeaderCell to the top of the view so HeaderCell gets positioned under NavigationBar.
- `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None`. Using this made the HeaderCell position itself starting from the top of Status Bar so half of the Header seems under status bar. *(Also Navigation Bar - Bar Tint forces to become dull gray ignoring whatever I choose, so not really convenient)* [image]

---

I want to ask

- Is there a way to not to make Status Bar opaque & make it solid? (I have the `Status Bar - Inherred` on Storyboard).
- Otherwise, is there a way to prevent this behaviour? Maybe considering status bar solid; or maybe giving the Header Cell a space or position HeaderCell starting under the Status bar after the Navigation Bar gets hidden?

---

Comment: You could set up the constraints so that the table view does not overlap with the status bar.

Comment: For the table view? Constraints seem disabled for Table View

Comment: have you considered hiding the status bar?

Comment: @user3353890 I want to keep the status bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no luck getting it with TableViewController, here is my workaround...

- Created a new ViewController
- Unchecked 'Adjust Scroll View Insets'
- Copied the TableView from TableViewController into ViewController's View.
- Added constraints to TableView *(Top/Bottom/Left -20/Right 20).*
- In AppDelegate, give white colour to Status Bar.